# Como seleccionar un solo codigo de color de una imagen con opencv

Tags: python, opencv

[[image: Imagen de colores[1]]
Lo que quiero hacer es extraer la parte marrón de la imagen, que viene a ser solo un solo código de color, utilizando opencv.
Me vendría bien su ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenido Joel Frank a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Por favor, añade el código de lo que hayas intentado hacer hasta ahora, y con que dificultades te has encontrado.